# show the first element in the dom and hide other all using css in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am working on the angular forms where i have to display the validation errors. To do this i have implemented the array of error to display in the view. but the issue with my dom structure is if i get multiple validation issue for the form element then all errors are getting displayed. But what i am expecting is to display one error message after resolving the first error i have to display it other.
How to show the first error using css or any other way to implement it in angular.
 **element will not get build if it doesn't have error.**

```
<div>
<error></error>
</div>
<div>
//error element will not build if it does't have error
</div>
<div>
<error></error>
</div>
```

[image: DOM structure]

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: @Chellappanவ i have created the sample view which i was expecting you can check the DOM. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkjep8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can has a function getError

```
  getError(control:any):string
  {
    if (control.errors)
    {
      if (control.errors.minlength)
          return "Min lengh "+control.errors.minlength.requiredLength
      if (control.errors.email)
          return "invalid email"
      ....
    }
    return ""
  }
```

And you write some like

```
 <mat-error>
      {{getError(form.get('email')}}
 </mat-error>
```

**Update** idea stolen from [this amazing entry of Netanet Basal](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-forms-error-messages-magically-appear-1e32350b7fa5), we can improve our function getError if you define a object like

```
export const defaultErrors = {
  required: (error)=>"This field is required",
  minlength: ({requiredLength,actualLength})=>"Expect "+requiredLength+" but got "+actualLength,
    email:(error)=>"invalid email",

}
```

Yes, is an object, each property is a function

Our function getError is like

```
  getError(control)
  {
    const firstKey = Object.keys(control.errors)[0];
    return defaultErrors[firstKey]?defaultErrors[firstKey](control.errors[firstKey]):
                                   "unknowed error"
  }
```